# It shows segmentation dump error when I use it

Tags: c++

Is there some kind of problem with this function as I have tried displacing each command but it still shows segmentation error

```
string splitSentence(string str)
    {
        string appendedWords{""},xx;
        for(int i=0 ; i < str.length();i++)
        {
            xx = str[i];
            if (xx == " ")
            {
                
                appendedWords = "";
            }
            else 
            {
                appendedWords = appendedWords + xx;
                
            }        
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tip: Don't forget that `x = x + y` is often better written as `x += y`.

Comment: There is no `return` statement even though function is declared to return a `string`.

Comment: Are you trying to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-words-of-a-string)?

Comment: Turn on all compiler warnings, or actually read the compiler warnings that you ignored.  Even better, tell your compiler to treat warnings as errors so that you are forced to read them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what your program should do, because now it only finds the last word in your string.

I just summarized the comments and improved your code a little bit. [Code](http://cpp.sh/9exfx)

Changed parts:

1. pass Strings by reference
2. str.length() returns an unsigned integer whilst you were using an integer, this caused a compiler warning
3. used x+=y instead of x = x + y as tadman pointed out
4. added return statement